# How to click on same name buttons with dynamic xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If there is 4 buttons with same name and dynamic x path then how to click on them below find my xpath for the buttons.

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div‌​/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a/div[2]/button")).click();
dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div‌​/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/div[2]/button")).click();
dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div‌​/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/div[2]/button")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic XPath? You can use relative xpath of parent node to identify all this buttons. You need to provide more information to get the answer.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. You can use [] to distinguish it. For e.g. my xpath is [@id='youama-email'] for four element 

Then [@id='youama-email'][0] ,[@id='youama-email'][1], [@id='youama-email'][2], [@id='youama-email'][3] something like this works.

Comment: See, suppose there are 3 users with U1, U2, U3 and in-front of every user join button is available. Every time Position of U1, U2, U3 changing and ultimately join button position also  changing. If i want click on U2 only then how to click on it?

Comment: 1st xpath- dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a/div[2]/button")).click();     2nd xpth- dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/div[2]/button")).click();       3rd xpath- dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/div[2]/button")).click();  .Here button name is name

Comment: Can you provide the html structure or website url for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Hi after viewing your xpath pattern you can do it like below to handle them dynamically

```
// hi in your case you can do it like below 
String MyFirstXpath = "html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div‌​/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[";
String MySecondXpath = "]/a/div[2]/button";

Please not you can increase or decrease the value of x and i as per your requirement 
int x= 3;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    System.out.println("Myxpath is : " + MyFirstXpath + x + MySecondXpath);
    // here you can perform the operation of click
     dr.findElement(By.xpath(MyFirstXpath +x + MySecondXpath)).click();
        x++;
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately  your code is not working. Because for loop  execute 3 time and button position not fixed. 3 times it clicking on 3 buttons

Comment: ok,what do u mean by button positions are not fixed ,yes it will click on three different buttons ,please be more specific so that any body can help

Comment: also can you copy paste xpath for buttons for 3 time page load so that i can have a clear idea

Comment: ok. 1st- html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/div[2]/button   2nd- html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/div[2]/button 3rd- html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section/section/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a/div[2]/button

Comment: hi this is xpath for same button but for three page load is it correct ?

Comment: User1           Join                                                                                              User2           Join                                                                                             User3           Join              Here every time 3 user position is changing. So How can i click on particular user join button every time. eg user 2